# Questions about calculating time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

[image]

I tried to solve this question and I know the answer should be O(n^2) and omega(n^2). But the solution for part b is a bit confusing. I don't know why we need to choose n/2 to calculate omega. Can someone kindly tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

n/2 is the average value of i.

This is because i goes from 1 to n:

Sum up all values of i you get n*(n+1)/2, divide that by n to get the average value of i (because you use i n times in total) and you get n/2 + 1/2 ~= n/2.